# servlet init exception running jersey servlet on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey, glassfish

i'm trying to deploy a rest application on tomcat7 that is running on ubuntu. After deploying the `.war` file using the application manager, when i access the url, its thrown me an exception.

It's important to say that, when i threw the `.war` on tomcat running on windows, it worked perfetly. I was running the latest versions of `JRE` and `JDK`.

I've tried everything i could find on the internet, but none worked so far. The error stack can be found below.

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw
>   exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web
>   Application threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   br/unicamp/ft/courseviewer/resource/TodasDisciplinasResource :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   br.unicamp.ft.courseviewer.resource.TodasDisciplinasResource)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:3111)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1348)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1828)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$6.run(ReflectionHelper.java:374)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$6.run(ReflectionHelper.java:369)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.getClassForName(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:257)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:219)
>     org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:1495)
>     org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:169)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:883)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:840)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.(ResourceConfig.java:1171)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.(ResourceConfig.java:1144)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1140)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:299)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:311)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is my jdk version.

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

Both `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` are pointing to the right place `/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_79` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch in Java version on your local machine and your Ubuntu server. I think you have Java 8 on your local machine that you used to generate your war file. You should either update Java on your server or compile with a JDK 7 to generate your war file. You can use your IDE to compile with a different version.

Comment: well...it worked, too simple and i could'nt figure out what were. Thank you.